# Blank sequences do not display anymore as continuous lines

Tags: front-end, fonts, display

`BlankSequence[]` and `BlankNullSequence[]` **"suddenly"** do not display anymore as "continuous lines" in my **v.10.0.1 (OSX)** (of course even computer reboot did not help) :

They look now like that :

[image]

but few days ago in this same **v.10.0.1** they used to look like in version 9 :

[image]

Does somebody know why it has suddenly changed ?
Does anyone has the same behaviour ?

Comment: This is due to the fact that v10 uses a different font than v9.

Comment: I think it *is* useful to distinguish between the different functions at first glance.

Comment: Related: [Mathematica 10 Notebook Fonts Look Bad](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55071/18476)

Comment: @Karsten7. My post was not clear, i will do an edit : i mean that the Blank Sequence in version 10 used to look like in v.9, but "suddenly" it's gone !

Comment: @YvesKlett I agree of course. Actually my first version of the post was not clear. The underscores used to be displayed as continuous lines in my **v.10** !. Something happened and I wonder if something else is affected.

Comment: Try removing the v10 cache in `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd`. That worked for me with other [issues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4886/52).

Comment: This depends on the font (stylesheet), font rendering settings, your operating system, etc. Why is it a problem?  I can see the separators between the `_` characters in M10 OSX 10.10.

Comment: I agree with Yves Klett & Szabolcs, it's useful to distinguish the 3 pattern types.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer:

> I think it is useful to distinguish between the different functions at first glance. – Yves Klett Nov 25 '14 at 15:44
>
> This depends on the font (stylesheet), font rendering settings, your operating system, etc. Why is it a problem? I can see the separators between the _ characters in M10 OSX 10.10. – Szabolcs Nov 25 '14 at 16:43
>
> I agree with Yves Klett & Szabolcs, it's useful to distinguish the 3 pattern types. – alancalvitti Nov 25 '14 at 17:08